# remove rows if it is negative number

Tags: r, dataframe, row

If my data.frame looks like:

```
   A     B       C
1 10 James    Math
2 -1  Tony Science
3 -5 Kevin    Math
4 11 Chris    Math
5 13   Min English
```

I want to remove rows if the value of `A` has a negative number 
like this:

```
   A     B       C
1 10 James    Math
4 11 Chris    Math
5 13   Min English
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj picking up some r after answering so many regex questions in r/regex? :}

Comment: @rawr ya, i know basic r .. If I have time, I should fully involve in this tag.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
df <- df[df$A >= 0, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
sample = sample[sample['A'] >= 0 ]
```